# error in passing NSMutableArray from NSObject To ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I have a MutableArray in NSObject Class i want to pass the NSMutableArray to detailViewController then i want to display the NSMutableArray in tableView(detailViewController).In this project i have a two view controller one is firstViewcontroller and detailviewcontroller.the problem is the data cannot pass from NSObject.Give me an idea if you want more Information Please ask.

peripheralmanager.m

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central 
didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral 
 advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData 
              RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{

  NSLog(@"didDiscoverPeriphera.peripheral: %@ rssi: %@, UUID:%@ advertisementData:%@", peripheral,RSSI,peripheral.UUID, [advertisementData description]);

  targetPeripheral = peripheral;
  peripheral.delegate = self;
  //  [[centralManager retrievePeripherals:NSArray arrayWithObject:(id)peripheral.UUID] ];
  //  rssilabel.text=[RSSI stringValue];
  if (!peripheral.isConnected)
  {
  [centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
  }
  // MeBleAppDelegate *appdelegate=(MeBleAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
  MeBleDetailViewController *obj=[[MeBleDetailViewController alloc]init];
  // MeBleDetailViewController *obj=[[appdelegate sharedappdelegate].navigationController objectATindex:MeBleDetailViewController];
  obj.dataArray=self.mutableArray;
  [self.mutableArray addObject:peripheral];
  printf("New UUId,addin\r\n");

}
```

detailviewcontroller.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  //NSMutableArray *dataArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  [super viewDidLoad];
  NSLog(@"%@",self.dataArray);
  NSLog(@"%@",objCurrentDevice.mutableArray);
  //  PeripheralManager *peripheralmanager=[[PeripheralManager alloc]init];
  self.label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ",dataArray];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  // [self.dataArray addObject:objCurrentDevice.mutableArray];

  appDelegate.arrDevices=dataArray;
  appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
  // write below line in any function in this file
  // NSLog(@"%d",[appDelegate.arrDevices count]);  
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier=@"Cell1";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
  if(cell==nil)
  {
    cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

    cell.textLabel.text=[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     //  PeripheralManager *objtemp=[[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]deviceName];
     NSLog(@"%@",objCurrentDevice.deviceName);
    return cell;
}
```

Error Message

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '***    -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

*** First throw call stack:

(0x356c888f 0x37a6f259 0x3561d1d7 0x164db 0x33135c8b 0x331421e9 0x33142059 0x33141f3f 0x331417c1 0x33141503 0x33135aff 0x331357d5 0x331ae903 0x33228627 0x351e2933 0x3569ca33 0x3569c699 0x3569b26f 0x3561e4a5 0x3561e36d 0x372ba439 0x3312acd5 0x1500f 0x14fb4)

terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

I want output like this image..Please Give an idea..Please Ask Me for More Information.

[image]

Comment: i think `[self.mutableArray addObject:peripheral];` may add "nil"

Comment: How many times are you going to ask the same question?

Comment: @Abizern Still in error i tried so many ways.don't get angry cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Designated intializer** to solve this issue

In your **FirstViewController**

```
-(id)initwithData (NSArray*)array
{
  //store the data in array
}
```

In the DetailedViewController you can call this method..

```
MeBleDetailViewController *obj=[[MeBleDetailViewController alloc]initwithData:yournsarrayname];
```

You can see your array will be loaded with the data

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you read the exception message:

```
-[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

This exception has nothing to do with passing the array around, it relates to how you are populating the array.  Cocoa collection classes cannot hold `nil` pointers (see `NSNull` if you ever want something like that) and you are attempting to put a `nil` pointer into the array, which it's taking exception to (literally).

Add some guard code:

```
obj.dataArray=self.mutableArray;
if (peripheral != nil)
    [self.mutableArray addObject:peripheral];
```

Comment: @prem OK, you'll need to post the symbolic stacktrace (a list of addresses isn't sufficient).

Comment: @Abizern Still in error i tried so many ways.
 don't get angry cool.